# Why Context.getResource().getXml(R.xml....).getAttributeValue(String namespace, String key) with gradle 3.0.1 (4.1) is error?)

Tags: java, android, xml

I want parse a color hexa string (example: "#dadada") with xml file but I have a problem.

- With classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2' (gradle 3.5-all-zip), the function in title return correct "#dadada".
- With classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1' (gradle 4.1-all-zip), the function in title return incorrect "#ffdadada" => why auto add "ff" in result???

My example xml data:

```
<mydata>
  <test bg_color="#dadada" />
 </mydata>
```

Please help me, thank you :D

Comment: The first two digits are the alpha, does it break anything?  If not, should be fine.

Comment: @Phix I know that but why auto add the alpha to result?

Comment: Couldn't find anything in the changelogs, probably somewhere between 3.5 and 4.1 it was implemented for whatever reason.